# Java calculations for calculating the volume of a cylinder and elliptical cylinder

Tags: java, geometry

Here is my calculations for a circular (regular) cylinder

```
volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(length / 2.0, 2) * depth;
```

Here are my calculations for an elliptical cylinder

```
volume = Math.PI * Math.pow(length * width, 2) * depth;
```

When I run it as a circle it comes out fine, but when I run it as an oval it returns a huge number.  I'm not sure if my calculations are wrong or what.

Answer (score 2):

```
volume = Math.PI * length * width * depth / 4; // div by 4
```

It's really (length/2) * (width/2), but we can simplify it to (length * width / 4)

Comment: @glowcoder:  Here's what I come up with after your calculations:  Round-157 cubic ft.  Oval-3,926 cubic ft.  This is figuring a 10' round tub by 2' deep.

Comment: @Mike fixed. We shouldn't have `Math.pow` in there at all for the volume.

Comment: @glowcoder:  I come up with the same results for an oval or circle.  Are the other calculations correct for a circle?

Comment: +1: glowcoder's math is correct. that is the correct formula for the volume of an eliptical cylinder.

Comment: @J T, that is correct after the correction, the thread wad following an earlier answer.

Comment: If you have a circle of radius r, and an oval (actually called an ellipse) of width w and height h, and w == h, and h == r, then you should expect that the oval is really just a circle, so they should produce the same volume.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top, the volume for the oval (elliptical cylinder) is not correct dimensionally. It [should be](http://www.abe.msstate.edu/~fto/tools/vol/ellipsetank.html)

```
volume = Math.PI * (length * width) / 4.0 * depth;
```

Comment: When I change it I come up with the same results for round or oval.

Comment: Yes, if width = length, your oval and circle are the same. If width < length, your oval will be smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Mike,

Test your formula against Wolfram Alpha:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/entities/calculators/elliptic_cylinder_volume/1n/ld/39/

Remember that:

- semi-major axis is length divided by two
- semi-minor axis is width divided by two
- Length is the case of wolfram alpha, is actually what you refer to as depth